# Is there a better way to add several words to a Set at once?

Tags: java, hashset

I was just wondering, what is the best way to add several items to a HashSet at once?

I'm working on a homework assignment where the object is to iterate through a .java file and count the keywords in the file. At the bottom of the assignment description it says ("Hint: Create a Set to hold all Java keywords")

I'm not completely familiar with HashSets, and I didn't know how to add a bulk of words at once, and I certainly didn't want to go through .add("final") .add("true") ..and so on for each keyword.

So, I created an array list with all of those words. I then used a for loop to loop through and add each one to the set.However, this seems redundant. If I've got all the keywords in an array, then I don't see why I would need to add them to a HashSet in order to complete the assignment.
But, for sake of learning some more on HashSets, is there a way to do this without the method I used(other than 1 by 1)?

```
String[] aryKeywords = { "abstract", "asset", "boolean", "break", "byte", "case", "catch", "char", "class", "const", "continue", "default", "do", "double", "else", "enum", "extends", "final", "finally", "float", "for", "goto", "if", "implements", "import", "instanceof", "int", "interface", "long", "native", "new", "package", "private", "protected", "public", "return", "short", "static", "strictftp", "super", "switch", "synchronized", "this", "throw", "throws", "transient", "try", "void", "volatile", "while", "false", "null", "true" };    
    Set<String> jKeywords = new HashSet<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < aryKeywords.length; i++) {
        jKeywords.add(aryKeywords[i]);
    }
```

Thanks for any insight!

Comment: I guess the assignment requires you to count _distinct_ keywords in the file. Adding the words to a Set is an easy way to filter out duplicates; the resulting set size is the number of distinct keywords.

Comment: Good point. Now that you've brought that up, I can see that is probably the intent. Now, I must go through and edit my homework! I've got it completed counting ALL keywords. http://pastebin.com/m7kWzhie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jon Skeet's answer is correct. Another (supposedly faster, according to its documentation) approach is:

```
Set<String> jKeywords = new HashSet<String>();
Collections.addAll(jKeywords, aryKeywords);
```

Or to specify them inline (to mirror Jon's answer):

```
Collections.addAll(jKeywords, "abstract", "asset", "boolean", /* ... */);
```

Comment: I think unless I had evidence that the performance of this piece of code was significant overall, I'd probably stick with `asList` - it looks cleaner to me. Worth knowing about `Collections.addAll` though - thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You could use:

```
Set<String> jKeywords = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(aryKeywords));
```

Or if you want to specify them inline:

```
Set<String> jKeywords = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(
    "abstract", "asset", "boolean", /* etc */));
```

If you're ever in a situation where you've already *got* a set, you can use `addAll`:

```
jKeywords.addAll(Arrays.asList(extraMembers));
```

Comment: Prefer to use `Collections.addAll(foo, bar)` as opposed to `foo.addAll(Arrays.asList(bar))`. The documentation for the former claims to be faster.

Comment: Thanks for the info guys. I remember, albeit vaguely, reading something about the Collections.addAll() when I was in class a few days ago. --Thanks to all who answered.

Answer (score 1):

you could do

```
jKeywords.addAll(Arrays.<String>asList(aryKeywords));
```

but that adds more garbage for somewhat cleaner code

Comment: +1 for the caution about generating garbage.  It is not usually an important issue ... but then neither is avoiding the loop :-)

Answer (score 0):

There's some VARIANTS of the same thing (the double {{ trick, which I don't like, but if you really want I'll menion), but no, Java doesn't really have a perfect answer here. For you. Another variation is the String[] you did, followed by Arrays.asList it into a List and then set.addAll . From an efficiency POV, none are particularly great.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Arrays.asList()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29):

```
Set<String> jKeywords = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(aryKeywords));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Set<String> jKeywords = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(aryKeywords));
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can bypass representing you items as an array. But, you can add them all at once by using a construct like

```
new HashSet (Arrays.asList(aryKeywords));
```